# C# sent email is not shown perfectly in Outlook Desktop Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, outlook, email-client

I am sending an email with WCF service in C#.

Code for sending email is like this-

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage
{
    Subject = BuildStringFromTemplate(subject, notificationEmail.Values),
    Body = BuildStringFromTemplate(body, notificationEmail.Values),
    From = new MailAddress(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromOverride) ? fromOverride : _from),
    IsBodyHtml = true
};

message.To.Add(new MailAddress(notificationEmail.Email));

try
{
    string messageId;

    if (notificationEmail.EventTypeId == EventType.CentralRatingSafetyContact.ToGuid() ||
        notificationEmail.EventTypeId == EventType.CentralRatingResultsContact.ToGuid())
    {
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        messageId = SendRawEmailBySimpleEmailService(new[] { notificationEmail.Email }, message.Subject, message);
    }
    else
    {
        messageId = SendBySimpleEmailService(new[] { notificationEmail.Email }, message.Subject, message, ccEmails);
    }

    if (notificationEmail.EventTypeId == EventType.SurveyInviteEmail.ToGuid())
    {
        StudyRaterEmail studyRaterEmail = (StudyRaterEmail)notificationEmail;
        _preQualificationBl.CreateSurveyHistory(studyRaterEmail.SurveyRevisionId, studyRaterEmail.HystoryId,
            studyId, studyRaterEmail.EmailGuid,
            messageId, studyRaterEmail.EventTypeId, studyRaterEmail.ResendMessage, operatedBy);
    }
    else if (notificationEmail.EventTypeId == EventType.SurveyMemoEmail.ToGuid())
    {
        StudyRaterEmail studyRaterEmail = (StudyRaterEmail)notificationEmail;
        _preQualificationBl.CreateSurveyMemo(studyRaterEmail.SurveyId, messageId,
            studyRaterEmail.EventTypeId, operatedBy);
    }
    else
    {
        _eventNotificationBl.NotifyEmailSent(notificationEmail.EventTypeId, notificationEmail, messageId, operatedBy);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Errors.Add(ex);
}
```

This service is called from ASP.Net MVC 4.

Email is sent perfectly.

It is perfect in Gmail, Yahoo even in Outlook and Outlook WebApp.

### Outlook-

[image: Outlook]

### Outlook Web App-

[image: Outlook WEb App]

### Gmail-

[image: Gmail]

But it is not showing perfectly in **Outlook Desktop Client**-

[image: Outlook Desktop Client]

---

---

If we forward this email from outlook desktop client to another email, it is also seen again.

So, it is only not shown in Outlook Desktop Client, but I am not getting any reason why this is happening.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Outlook (desktop) is one of the worst email renderers I've ever had the misfortune of dealing with. Does anyone know if it still use a stub of Word to render HTML? The issue is not to do with your code, it'll be your HTML using tags that Outlook renders badly. Plenty of resources and workarounds online.

Comment: if you can post some code of the email we have have look to see whats broken and where.
@Equalsk Yes unfortunately outlook still uses word to render emails. Last release MOS2016 is using word has its own rendering issues.